# aggregate variance or standard deviation similarly as weighted mean

Tags: variance, descriptive-statistics, weighted-mean

Say I have several regions' melon produce data. I wish to measure the variability of melon weight in each area, and summarize these as an overall variability metric accounting for the different sizes of each area. In equation, it will be similar to [weighted arithmetic mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_arithmetic_mean#Mathematical_definition):

$$
\frac{\sum_i Variability(i) Area_i}{\sum_i Area_i}
$$

My question is, is it more suitable to use standard deviation or variance to measure variability in this equation, or it does not matter? I feel like standard deviation may have some bias issues, but am not able to write it explicitly.

Comment: Does this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Linear_combinations help?

Comment: @AlexJ I don't really think it's related to this kind of linear combination. The variability in different areas are considered to be independent with each other. The link does not mention weighting either.

Comment: Yeah right I see. I suspect you probably can modify some result either from stratified sampling https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stratified_sampling or cluster sampling, where you treat the areas as either a stratum or a cluster (depending on how the data is collected) and then use the formulae for aggregating the stratum (or cluster) level variances into an overall variance. Sorry, I don't have a good reference for this off the top of my head but hopefully that can point you in the right direction